# Get file commit hash from github Api for whole directory

Tags: github, github-api

How can I get the latest commit in a directory using Github API?

What I have been doing is getting the directory contents for all files and then for each file I have been requesting it's commits.

What I thought of doing is mapping commit hash for all files. And then if some of them are the same I could "save" some API calls to Github.

Is this possible or is there any other way?

Answer (score -1):

You can easily achieve this, but I suggest for you to use a database for this purpose. I suggest for you to use the following database tables to store the data:

> files(id, filepath, lasthash_id)
>
> hashes(id, hash)
>
> files_of_hash(id, file_id, hash_id)

Each record of files will represent a file, along with the last hash id which lastly occurred to the file. hashes will contain a record for each hash. Each record in files_of_hash will represent a pair of a file and a hash. The relation would mean that a given file was created, modified or removed in a commit.

Now, if you run

```
git log
```

you will get all the hashes, but you will need to somehow parse the result. This way you will get the initial records to be stored into hashes. Now, iterate through all the hashes and run

```
$ git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r <yourhash>
```

you will get the list of files. You will need to iterate through the results and check whether they exist in the files table. If not, insert it into files. You will need to insert it into files_of_hash anyway. When you finish this iteration, update files and change lasthash_id to the newest hash_id if they differ.

Now, you will be able to get the last hash of each file and all hashes.

Afterwards, whenever you run a

```
git pull
```

you will have to act almost similarly as in the case of the initial filling of data, but you will need to avoid the repeated of handling of hashes you already had.

Also, if you are using multiple branches, you might want to store the branch for each commit hash, but that would be a second version of this approach.

Comment: Thank you @Lajos, but this is not possible. We are an app and we don't want to pull clients source code for now (it is a better solution that we thought of but it's not in our main KPI now the ROI is low)

Comment: @QauliGuy of course you can apply the ideas describe in this answer to your specific case. You can create an API on the central repo and execute there the commands. In this case you will not have to pull the source-code to your device and you will not have to pull anything at all. I am assuming here that there is a central repo.

Comment: I am sorry @Lajos but we can only use Github API for now